# How do I download a PDF, then output a chunk of text?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, linux-mint, pdf, text

My city water bill is emailed to me every month as a link to the current PDF hosted on their server. So I can easily download this PDF any time I want. How do I take that PDF and extract my account balance? Emailing it, or texting or something.

Comment: There is actually NO login needed to download.

Comment: And I would really like to be able to automate this with cron or something. And I checked, the file link is the same every month.

Answer (score 1):

The code would vary depending on the details, but the general approach would be:

- Log in to the web site (?)
- Download the page linking to the file using `wget` or `curl`
- Get the link to the pdf from the page
- Download the file using `wget` or `curl`
- Extract the text from the pdf with `pdftotext` from poppler-utils or similar
- Use `grep` or so to get the data you want from the text result

The most complicated part would be the login process, if it's needed.

---

As you comment you do not need to log in, and have a fixed URL, that simplifies it of course.
We can download the PDF and use the text content directly to extract the data. 
Below is an example to extract a line from a sample pdf file. That line contains the word `ghostview` and a version number, which could be used as example value.

```
$ u='http://www.wave.org.au/jupgrade/images/sample.pdf'
$ curl -s "$u" | pdftotext - - | grep 'ghostscript '
• ghostscript ≥ 5.10 (for example from Red Hat Contrib) and ghostview
```

The next step could be to extract the plain numerical value.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible using [`pdftotext`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pdftotext.1):

```
$ pdftotext -layout transaction.pdf - | grep -C1 amount
                 19876.0
amount paid
```

The program is part of the `poppler-utils` package, which can be installed using:

```
sudo apt-get install poppler-utils
```

The `-layout` option is used to make `pdftotext` adhere to the PDF layout as closely as it can (otherwise the `amount paid` in my PDF's table layout is quite far from the amount in text form).

Comment: what does -C1 do?

Comment: @user54735 one line of context around the match - it makes grep print the lines before and after the line that matched. You may be lucky enough to get whatever you grep for directly, but in my case they were on different, but adjacent lines.